How to get a list of recently completed tasks from vcenter using govmomi
I want to get a list of recently completed vcenter tasks using govmomi and I'm using the following code.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/vmware/govmomi"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/property"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/view"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25/mo"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25/soap"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Replace these with your vCenter credentials
    vcURL := "https://vcenter urlom/sdk"
    username := "Admin"
    password := "password"

    // Create a new client
    u, err := soap.ParseURL(vcURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    u.User = url.UserPassword(username, password)
    client, err := govmomi.NewClient(ctx, u, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    m := view.NewManager(client.Client)
    for {
        // Create a container view of Task entities
        v, err := m.CreateContainerView(ctx, client.ServiceContent.RootFolder, []string{"ManagedEntity"}, true)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        vms, _ := v.Find(ctx, []string{"Task"}, property.Filter{})
        if len(vms) > 0 {
            fmt.Println(vms)
        }
        defer v.Destroy(ctx)

        // Retrieve all Task entities
        var tasks []mo.Task
        err = v.Retrieve(ctx, []string{"Task"}, []string{"info"}, &tasks)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // Print task details
        for _, task := range tasks {
            fmt.Printf("Task Name: %s\n", task.Info.Name)
        }
    }

But this return nothing. When I tried VirtualMachine instead of Task it returned vm details. But it is not returning task details.
Can anyone help with this?
